# SMS integration in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sms-gateway

Is there any gem or API's that provides the SMS integration in rails 3 application. I tried with sms_fu but the carrier is not available for India. Is any other alternative is there. Please help me as soon as possible. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can any help me on this, im waiting some one to reply this.

Comment: Check out Twillio, they're global http://www.twilio.com/sms

Comment: They are not providing for all operators.

Answer (score 3):

Use Twilio Api 
First register in twilio and get sample Phone-No  and follow the below link

http://www.twilio.com/docs/ruby/install